# Backwards Euler Method's error converges to step size (Python)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, computational-mathematics, python, eulers-method

I am trying to programmatically solve the ODE,
$$\displaystyle Y'( t) =-Y( t) +\frac{1}{1+t^{2}} +\tan^{-1}( t)$$
with initial condition $Y(0)=0$. I know the analytical solution is $\displaystyle Y( t) =\tan^{-1}( t)$.

I am using the formula for the backwards Euler Method, $$\displaystyle \boxed{y_{n+1} =y_{n} +hf( t_{n+1} ,\ y_{n+1})}$$
and am using an initial guess value as instructed from a book
$\displaystyle \overset{( 0)}{y_{n+1}} =y_{n+1,\ FE}$ which I obtain from the forward Euler Method, and then iterate over $$\displaystyle \overset{( k)}{y_{n+1}} =y_{n} +hf( t_{n+1} ,\ \overset{( k-1)}{y_{n+1})}$$
until it is sufficient enough to stop.

I have used code in python (found at the end), and have plotted the results obtained using both the forwards and backwards Euler Method for reference, as well as the difference of each method from the 'true result'.
[Forwards and Backwards Euler Method Plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iL7H0.png)

My main question is regarding the difference of the backwards Euler Method's result from the true result obtained from np.arctan(t), and why it converges to the step size $h$.

The code,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

h = 0.01 # step size
t0 = 0; tf = 10
numel = int(np.floor(((tf-t0)/h) + 1))

t = np.linspace(t0, tf, numel)
yf = np.zeros(numel) # forwards array
ybold = np.zeros(numel) # backwards arrays
ybnew = np.zeros(numel)
ytrue = np.zeros(numel)

yf[0] = 0; ybold[0] = 0; ybnew[0] = 0; # initial condition

for i in range(0, numel-1):
  # Forward Method
  yf[i+1] = yf[i] + h*(-yf[i] + 1/(1+(t[i]**2)) + np.arctan(t[i]))

  # Backward Method
  ybold[i+1] = yf[i+1]
  c = 0
  diff = 1
  while  diff > 0.00001 and c < 5:
    ybnew[i+1] = ybnew[i] + h*(-ybold[i+1] + 1/(1+(t[i+1]**2)) + np.arctan(t[i+1]))
    diff = ybnew[i+1] - ybold[i+1]
    ybold[i+1] = ybnew[i+1]
    c = c + 1

ytrue = np.arctan(t)
```

I believe I could have made a mistake when coding it, although if I have my mistake eludes me. Or, I am misunderstanding the errors of the Euler Methods.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I can't make sense of what is happening. The forward Euler method for the DE should be $$y_{n+1}=y_{n}+h\left(-y_{n}+\frac{1}{1+t_{n}^{2}}+\arctan(t_{n})\right)$$ while the backward Euler should be \begin{align} y_{n+1}&=y_{n}+h\left(-y_{n+1}+\frac{1}{1+t_{n+1}^{2}}+\arctan(t_{n+1})\right) \\ \implies y_{n+1} &= \frac{1}{(1 + h)} \left[ y_{n} + h \left(\frac{1}{1+t_{n+1}^{2}} + \arctan(t_{n+1}) \right) \right]\end{align} It is not obvious to me why you can't just use the initial condition as is and instead need to use one forward Euler step, nor why you are doing this at each iteration.

Comment: You might want to use `abs(diff)` to control the error.

Comment: Hello, thank you both for the comments. 

 I repeat the iteration to gain a better approximation of the 'true' value of $y_{n+1}$ for each time-step. I could just use the original value obtained from the forward Euler method, but the book I am following tells to iterate multiple times so that I sufficiently reach the 'truest' value.

@LutzLehmann Thank you very much this fixed my problem. I absolutely turned a blind eye to that. Could you please put it as an answer so I can accept it and close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  while  diff > 0.00001 and c < 5:
```

will break the loop when `diff = -1`, so change to absolute values for the error bound

```
  while  abs(diff) > 0.00001 and c < 5:
```

Note that for a first-order method an error proportional to the step size falls in the expected behavior.